What are the actual requirements to be able to review Staging Ground questions?
The announcement post mentions a minimum of 500 rep to be able to review Staging Ground questions.
A comment by staff adds the additional restriction that users need to have asked two questions.
I fulfil both requirements, so why do I still get a "Page not found" when trying to access Staging Ground?
It seems it has something to do with the Ask Wizard, as I am forced to use it when asking a new question (no toggle to turn it off):


You also have well-received questions, so it's not even something like "2 well received questions."

Related (the flip side of this): What's the actual criterion for questions to enter the Staging Ground? There is something definitely murky about the requirements. From what we know, your account should qualify as reviewer. Yet apparently it doesn't. In the question I linked, I also found another user in a similar situation. They have well-received answers and have more than enough reputation. Yet their question went through the SG.

Can you toggle the Ask Wizard on/off? I believe there's some relation to whatever criteria the Wizard follows.

@AbdulAzizBarkat No I can not. It forces me to use the Ask Wizard without the option to go back to the usual editor.

@JeanotZubler hmm, you should have enough well received questions that you should be able to turn the Ask Wizard off. Does anyone know the criteria for toggling off the Ask Wizard? I used to think it was something along the lines of 2-3 well received questions which matches up with the stated Staging Ground criteria (in fact the wizard is supposed to be the gateway to SG, questions asked without the wizard won't reach SG).

@AbdulAzizBarkat I know for a fact that I was able to turn off the Ask Wizard and have done so at a previous point. I am also pretty (though not entirely) sure that I had it turned off when I last asked a question.

@JeanotZubler yes, you didn't use the ask wizard for your last question (It shows up in timeline of the post if you did so)

@ThomA I don't "2 well received questions" are a requirement as my (mostly) niche questions mean my highest scoring only has a score of 2, the rest pretty much 0. But I can review Staging Ground items.

I was specifically talkming about the OP's, @A-Tech . They have several questions with a positive score (One had a score of 5); what I refer to as "well received". So I'm stating  that it's not like they have 7 questions all with a score of < 0; they have clearly contribute questions that are on-topic and "good".

@ThomA i misread, did not see the not even in your comment. Though you meant that it is an requierment

@Ðаn Actually, this sentence is correct. I have access to review queues. However the sentence directly after this is the problem: "This includes access to Staging Ground. "

While it's a bit counterintuitive, I'm marking this [status-completed] because the specific issue you were running into (not qualifying as a reviewer) was resolved by some tweaks we made to the system. The answer to your titular question is below.

Edit: The requirement for reviewers to have asked 2+ successful questions has been removed.

For Staging Ground, a user can either qualify as an asker or a reviewer - never both. (Under some circumstances, qualifying as neither is possible, too.)
There are two criteria the system checks to determine your status:

Do you have more than 500 rep?
Do you have two or more "successful" questions? For these purposes, a question is "successful" if it has a score of two or higher, or if the question has been answered. It also must not be closed or deleted.

To qualify as an asker, a user must have fewer than two successful questions.
To qualify as a reviewer, a user must have more than 500 reputation and two or more successful questions.
It's worth noting that this system isn't set in stone. We're open to considering changes to the system for granting asker/reviewer access, and we have a couple to consider on our plate already.

Note: This may not have been accurate for all users on release day. It should now be accurate.

So things like this example VLAZ found are just inaccuracies on release day that should be fixed?

Since I only have only asked one question, I would not be eligible to review in the staging ground?

@StephenRauch IIRC, mods always have access. But if you weren't a mod (or if I misremember), then no, you wouldn't be/aren't eligible

I'd suggest that earning some badges related to improving peoples questions should qualify to grant SG review access as well.  The explainer/refiner/illuminator (edit and answer), life jacket/lofe boat (answers that reverse down voted questions), maybe self-learner (positive self answered question), maybe editor/strunk and white/copy editor (editing posts).

"To qualify as an asker, a user must have fewer than two successful questions." What a bummer. Getting SG-feedback on complicated question could be useful even if one asked some (simpler?) successful questions already.

So to clarify, does this mean users who were part of the Beta, and thus whitelisted, but who wouldn't qualify in this scenario, have now lost access as reviewers? Or will they forever have access due to that whitelist?

"We're open to considering changes to the system for granting asker/reviewer access, and we have a couple to consider on our plate already." One thing to consider is that heavy curators are often the targets of revenge downvotes. (1/3)

I don't know exactly what qualifies as 'well-received' (answered, accepted, Q score, etc.; how it all plays together), but my own questions, for example, are all good questions (e.g. they don't merit downvotes or closure in and of themselves) yet they are all heavily downvoted by revenge downvoters periodically as I curate the site. While I do still have a few that are positively scored in aggregate, if I don't ask more (or if I don't stop curating) then that will likely change in the future, kicking me out of the program. (2/3)

So perhaps one additional criterion could be "or has earned the Instructor badge"... this way if you qualify, do 250 SG reviews, and then your question score drops, you still retain access as you clearly qualified at some point and have significant experience with the SG. Or just have earned a Steward gold badge in any of the traditional review queues. (3/3)

Question requirement is very limiting. I've got more than enough rep, but if I want to access Staging Ground I'd have to force asking a question just to qualify.
